# Ordering DIVs using flex and css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple 3-column structure which includes a *back* button, a *main* content page and a *forward* button:

```
<div class="container h100">
        <div class="row align-items-center h100">
            
            <div class="col-sm-2 align-self-center order-1" id="backbutton">
                <button>Back</button>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-md-8 align-self-center align-self-stretch" id="main">
                <p>Main content</p>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-sm-2 align-self-center order-1" id="backbutton">
                <button>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[current result on a large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiZCq.png)

On a smaller screen (e.g. phone), I would like the main content button to go to the top, and the back and next button on one row below (with back on the left and next on the right).

[expected result on a smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3osZf.png)

I've tried "order-1" and "order-12", but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to try this on your own. I understand getting frustrated with CSS (I was there too and asked a similar question a long time back).

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px;){
  .container{
    flex-flow: column;
  }
}
```

This should work but I would recommend trying [to learn flexbox](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  #btn1 {
    float: left;
  }
  #btn2 {
    float: right;
  }
  #main {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffe500;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    main content
  </div>
  <div id="btn">
    <button id="btn1">Back</button>
    <button id="btn2">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>```
````